# Using dnsmasq when not connected to the Internet

Tags: development, google-chrome, dns

I'm routing dns requests through dnsmasq so that domains I'm using for local development point to 127.0.0.1. This works great when I'm connected to the Internet via Wi-Fi or ethernet, but I start to have problems when I'm not connected to the Internet at all.

In dnsmasq.conf, I have this setting:

```
address=/gentoo/127.0.0.1
```

Turning off all network connections, I run:

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name test.gentoo
name: test.gentoo
ip_address: 127.0.0.1

$ ping test.gentoo
PING test.gentoo (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.177 ms
^C
--- test.gentoo ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.043/0.109/0.177/0.055 ms
```

So that seems to be working fine. But if I try to open http://test.gentoo/ in Chrome, I get the message:

> Unable to connect to the Internet Google Chrome can't display the
>   webpage because your computer isn't connected to the Internet.
>
> You can try to diagnose the problem by taking the following steps:
>
> Go to Applications > System Preferences > Network > Assist me to test
>   your connection. Error 106 (net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED): The
>   Internet connection has been lost.

Chrome sees that I don't have a network connection, and it doesn't even try to make the request.

Any idea how I can work around this? Can I create a dummy network interface to convince Chrome I'm connected to the Internet? Can I make it send the requests even though I'm not connected? Any other ideas?

I tried the solution at https://serverfault.com/q/22419/92378 but it did not work, as I'm on OS X 10.7.3, so resolver is ignored when not connected to a network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution on https://serverfault.com/q/22419/92378 is working for me (OS X 10.9.4). Just make sure to do this step:

Create a file /etc/resolver/whatever:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
domain .
```